# How to use Network Image in PDF Flutter

Tags: database, image, flutter, pdf

I have a database document where there is links available for multiple images. I want to display this images in pdf.

I am using `pdf: ^2.1.0` to edit the pdf file and `flutter_pdfview: ^1.0.1` to view the pdf.

I am currently displaying images like this but this can only display images from the asset

```
final profileImage = pw.MemoryImage(
  (await rootBundle.load('assets/images/image.png')).buffer.asUint8List(),
);

//Inside Widgets
pw.Image(profileImage)
```

I want to show images using a link but its not being possible.

Answer (score 2):

This will help you

```
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(imageUrl));
var data = response.bodyBytes;

Image(pdfW.MemoryImage(data),)
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer according to the guide(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), specifically add some context and a verbal explanation.